# How to auto connect to server?

Tags: android, jdbc, android-asynctask

I make a android application connect to server by using "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".
I make a class for creating a connection as a AsyncTask.

```
public class MySqlConnection extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Connection>{
      protected void onPreExecute() {
        //
      }

      protected Connection doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
           Connection con = null;      
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");            
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ip+"/"+db_name+"?user="+username+"&password="+password);
           return con;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Connection connection) {
         delegate.setConnection(connection);
      }
}
```

This class is called in OnCreate().

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(MainActivity.this,utils.getConnection(),ip, dbname, user, password, new ConnectionResult() {
            @Override
        public void setConnection(Connection con) {
           //set to static connection.
        }
       }
    sqlConnection.execute(1);
  }
```

It can work if a device can connect to server as initial.
But if I try to turn off Wifi, it cannot to re-connect by itself.
Client must restart the application for make it call OnCreate() again.

How to make it re-connection to server all the time?

Comment: Don't use JDBC from Android, use a web-service (e.g. using Spring Boot) to mediate between your application and the database.

Comment: Why I should not use JDBC? This application was created for using in a part of production  in factory. Client don't want to connect outside. However, If a JDBC cannot re-connect to server automatically. I'm ready to change to web-service if it can help to solve this problem.

Comment: Some JDBC drivers do have an auto-reconnect feature, but this is not specified by JDBC itself. The main problem is that JDBC drivers don't perform well on mobile connections (but maybe that isn't relevant for you), but a secondary problem is that you need to expose your database. REST APIs insulate your database from the rest of the world, and generally allow for better performance. Add to that that recent JDBC drivers are likely to use Java features that are not available on Android, this all leads me to recommend not to use JDBC on Android.